# ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet'

Tags: python, tensorflow

This error occurred, while my original code doesn't contain 'import resnet'.

It seems like the error occurred when import tensorflow.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step2_training.py", line 5, in <module>
    from class_coTrust import *
  File "/share/scratch/manqingdong/my_filename/class_coTrust.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "/share/scratch/manqingdong/my_filename/utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/resnet.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras_applications import resnet
ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet'
```

Answer (score 8):

the solution for tensorflow 2.4.0 is
`from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50`

Answer (score 2):

try resnet instead of resnet50

```
from keras.applications import resnet
model = resnet.ResNet50
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
```

try this

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But my code only contains `import tensorflow as tf`, I don't know why such error occurred because there is no `import resnet`  in my code, I didn't use resnet. The problem seems solved by deleting `tf.reset_default_graph()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `resnet` is not install. Could you try to install it using pip?

```
pip3 install resnet
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same situation after installing `Keras-Applications==1.0.6` and 
`Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.5`. Removing these two pip packages and reinstalling `tensorflow` solves the problem.